# how to take a picture fpga and verilog

Tags: fpga

I have cyclone II fpga and also ı have a camera attached to it.Fisrtly ı want to take a capture from camera and this capture is passing to fpga and ı want to take this capture from serial port.Can you give me ideas how can do this or are there any example code about this.I am working with verilog .

thanks for help...

Comment: We need more details. The Cyclone 2 only tells us what chip you're working with. I assume it's attached to a dev-board? (the DE2 perhaps?) And are you working with an RS232 port, or just one of the GPIO headers? 

Not only that, it's difficult to help without knowing anything about the camera. Is it dev-hardware, a hacked apart consumer digital camera, or are you even trying to trigger the shutter on a disposable kodak ;) 

Details please!

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have this  board http://www.knjn.com/docs/KNJN%20RS232%20FPGA%20boards.pdf  pluto 3 it has rs232 connection and ı have a cmos camera sensor attached to pluto 3's pins also ı have lens it is attached to cmos camera sensor. ı have a program.realterm.Datas are coming from fpga .fpga send to datas rs232 port program is writing this datas as a decimal numbers to a txt file.After I am opening this txt matlab but capture   is not image.only black nad white points ...

Answer (score 1):

You need to research how exactly the camera is hooked up to your FPGA and how exactly you need to communicate with it. Once you understand this protocol and it's connections, you'll be 90% of the way towards understanding what you need to do, or at least will be better able to ask more specific, intelligent questions. =)

For example, there is a chance that you are working with a camera over a bus called Camera Link. If so, you will need to read up on the protocol (e.g. starting with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_Link), and then determine if you are going to write a custom interface yourself in an HDL (like Verilog) or if you are going to try to obtain and use an existing design from a 3rd party.

Once you know how to get images, then you need to do the same discovery to figure out how you are going to send these images to your PC. Do you already know all about RS-232 and UARTs (or USB, or whatever you are using)? If not, you will need to learn enough to either implement these interfaces, or at least to interface with existing designs that you have obtained elsewhere.

In sort -- you really need to do more research before anyone can help you with any specific advice. =)

Comment: Thanks for answer.I have this board knjn.com/docs/KNJN%20RS232%20FPGA%20boards.pdf pluto 3 it has rs232 connection and ı have a cmos camera sensor attached to pluto 3's pins also ı have lens it is attached to cmos camera sensor. ı have a program.realterm.Datas are coming from fpga .fpga send to datas rs232 port program is writing this datas as a decimal numbers to a txt file.After I am opening this txt matlab but capture is not image.only black nad white points ...